# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js): TypeError: Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined at Object.loader

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel and vuejs to create event calendar. i am trying run `npm run dev` but there is an error

> ERROR in ./resources/js/components/CalendarComponent.vue Module build
> failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js): TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined
> at Object.loader (D:\20213\calendar_with_vue\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js:70:34)

Comment: Can you provide the full error log. And: Have you tried to update everything to the latest versions?

Comment: I am using vue 2 and install fullcalendar js for vue2.

Comment: here is full error log
PS D:\20213\calendar_with_vue> npm run dev

> @ dev D:\20213\calendar_with_vue
> npm run development


> @ development D:\20213\calendar_with_vue
> mix


✖ Mix
  Compiled with some errors in 3.00s

ERROR in ./resources/js/components/CalendarComponent.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined
    at Object.loader (D:\20213\calendar_with_vue\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js:70:34)

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same problem. And I use below command its work.Thanks

```
npm install vue-template-compiler@latest vue@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to incomplete dependencies. Try deleting node modules and installing again by npm i command.
Kindly share if it solved your problem. Otherwise share your package.json file this maybe due to a un-maintained package.
Thanks