# Problems building modules with webpack 5: Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, webpack

I am updating a Laravel project from Vue2 to Vue3 . Webpack 5 is used as the bundler. Now I have the problem that I get such an error when running "yarn run development".

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/Audit/ConfirmUpdateModal.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):
At least one <template> or <script> is required in a single file component.
```

This affects all vue components.
The webpack.mix.js looks like this.

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
    loader: {
        test: /node_modules\/.+\.(jsx|js)$/,
        loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window'

    },
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/i,
                loader: "vue-loader",
                options: {
                    esModule: true,
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules\/(?!vuetable-2)|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ],
})

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/vue.js', 'public/js')
    .js('node_modules/alpinejs/dist/module.esm.js','public/js/')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/pdf/audit.scss','public/css/pdf/')
    .sass('resources/sass/pdf/catalog-changelog.scss','public/css/pdf/')
    .sass('resources/sass/pdf/customer-certificate.scss','public/css/pdf/')
    .copy('node_modules/sp-sass/img/*.*','public/img/')
    .copy('resources/img/*.*','public/img/')
    .vue({ runtimeOnly: true, version: 3 })
    .sourceMaps(false)
    .version();
```

The package.json looks like this:

```js
 "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.3.4",
        "axios": "^1.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "q-flat": "1.0.7",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
        "vue-loader": "^17.2.2",
        "vuetable-2": "2.0.0-beta.4",
        "webpack": "^5.88.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "alpinejs": "^3.10.5",
        "vue-i18n": "^9.4.1",
        "vue-tour": "^2.0.0",
        "vue3-tour": "^0.3.4"
    },
```

I can rule out the possibility that there is an error in the Vue component. Now I have found this: [Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js): TypeError: Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined at Object.loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770596/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-vue-loader-dist-index-js-typeerror-c) but this article could not help me. I also tried to delete the node_modules folder and create a new one, but that didn't help either. I also tried other versions of vue-loader, but that didn't solve the problem either. I suspect that the problem is in the webpack.mix.js, where I did everything as suggested in the Laravel-Mix documentation.

Comment: Or is the part with ```javascript { test: /\.vue$/i, loader: "vue-loader",options: { esModule: true, } }, ``` superfluous as .vue() is used. I am unsure about this